# What are some good resources for understanding SNMP MIBs?

Tags: snmp, mib

I know a little about SNMP, but not enough. I need to develop an application that can read standard SNMP MIBs and read/write the various properties. The network end is no problem, but the actual MIBs and exactly what they may contain is something of a black art to me.

I believe I should be able to use LIBSMI to 'parse' the MIBs, but I don't really understand what the output of the 'parser' is going to be, and how best to use it.

All suggestions welcome...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of throwing you in the deep end, you might want to take a look at [net-snmp](http://www.net-snmp.org/). The default installation contains a number of standard mibs with their associated implementation. It also contains a utility (mib2c) that will generate boilerplate code from your mib files.

Once you've read your way through a couple of mibs you should have no trouble familiarising yourself with the way that snmp does things.

Answer (score 1):

Most standard MIB documents were defined in corresponding RFCs published at IETF.

http://www.ietf.org/

Please go to this site to find more details.

Answer (score 0):

Muonics [Mib Smithy User Guide](http://www.muonics.com/Docs/MIBSmithy/UserGuide/) provides a good overview of how to build a MIB, which can help you understand the necessary elements for parsing.

You should also look at the [ASN.1 ITU specification X.690](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.690-201508-I/en), because that is the language SNMP is defined in. It also helps if you scour the SNMP RFCs for any Bachus-Naur formatting in the SNMP RFCs. I'm going to suggest you start with RFC3642 and RFC2252.

Comment: Do you have any links or any additional details?